# Alter vs Modify vs Change (in Legal Documents)

Tags: meaning, differences, legalese

Consider the quote from ["What is a Grantor Trust" article](http://www.estateplanners.com/articles/what-is-a-grantor-trust/).

> This trust is revocable, which simply means **it can be altered, modified, and otherwise changed** or even terminated during the life of the grantor, provided that the grantor has full mental capacity.

As far as I could figure out from other forums words "alter" and "modified" mean "to change slightly", and "change" is more generic word and may also mean "replace" or "exchange for something else". The text in bold sounds to me like "*it can be slightly changed, slightly changed, and otherwise changed*". Are there some differences in meaning between "alter" and "modify" in this context or in general? Are they generally interchangeable?

Comment: You should ask a lawyer.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, is there a difference in general meaning of alter and modify? They seem to me interchangeable?

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary?

Comment: I think at least that you might find them used in different contexts. The use of all three in the context of your example is typical of legal language which aspires to cover all possibilities.

Comment: The most usual sense of 'modify' on this website ('_cute_, _little_, and _green_ modify the noun _frog_ in the phrase _the cute little green frog_') doesn't demand the 'make a slight change to' that the more general sense (_modified his Harley_) does. This is probably too broad a definition of this sense: [A modifier is a word or phrase that adds detail or description to a sentence.](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/36/)

Comment: meta: Used to have an OT clause for overly domain-specific terms such as these. General English meanings hardly ever correspond to domain-specific meanings and it is hazardous to apply commonly understood meanings in these contexts.

Comment: Furthermore, there's an important reason why a word is sometimes not used in isolation but followed by as many of its synonyms as may be required in legal drafting. You could always argue that what you did was to 'modify', not 'alter', if only *alter* had been mentioned. A valid argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your typical legalese. You'll note that lawyers love to use such legal doublets (cease and desist, furnish and supply, e.g.) or triplets (cancel, annul and set aside, e.g.) which for the rest of us are simple synonyms and thus pleonasms.

Answer (score 4):

The following information is culled from the website uslegal.com

[Alter](http://definitions.uslegal.com/a/alteration/) is defined as "to cause to become different in some particular characteristic . . . without changing into something else." *United States v. Kilbride, 2009 U.S. App. LEXIS 23722 (9th Cir. Ariz. Oct. 28, 2009)*

[Modification](http://definitions.uslegal.com/m/modification/) means “any alteration in the terms and conditions of a contract, including supplemental agreements, amendments, and extensions.”

Comment: so they are basically the same.